# openssl dgst verification - difference

Tags: openssl, cryptography, sha256, public-key-encryption, pyopenssl

I am using below test keypair and commands to sign and verify testfile.

`openssl dgst -sha256 -sign privkey -out sig.sha256 testfile`

`openssl dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -signature sig.sha256 testfile`

All working, until I copied over the testfile, sig.sha256 and pubkey.pem to another machine and ran verification, and it failed. This is consistent behaviour and fails everytime on that machine (Linux/Yocto).

Openssl version on the machine (x86-Ubuntu) where verification works -
`OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019`
`OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018 (compiled and installed on seperate path to try it out)`

Openssl version on the machine (ARM-Linux/Yocto) where verification fails -
`OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018`

Any pointer to debug this?

Comment: Failed how? How did you copy the file? Did you do a `sha256sum` over the file at both locations?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - the output of openssl verify command reports "Verified OK" on working machine and "Verification Failure" on the other. For the file integrity, verified checksum of all the files and they are same of both the machine... I am looking on how can I get logs of exactly what openssl is doing,.. tried with strace but looks same..

Comment: Quite commonly it's just a problem with the key pair. You could try and extract the public key from the private key, and then compare the public keys. Sorry if I have to ask this, but it is just too common that something goes wrong with key management. I could not directly find a change within the OpenSSL changelog.